# How do I word-wrap the inside of html tags while keeping the tags around both sides of the wraps

Tags: php, jquery, html

Upon further testing the provided solution to my problem which was to word-wrap text inside of the html tags and keep the original enclosing tags such as a `<p>` or a `<b>` or even an `<i>` tag around the words cut at a set position. This is useful for certain application that require a specific formatting to function for the front end. I have modified the code provided to try to achieve this however I have been unsuccessful with the challenging content used in this php example.

I could really use some assistance and I'm sure others could use this information to build dynamic html based books like I am trying to do. it isn't restricted to books there are also possibilities of sliders and other implementations. by not keeping the end tags around each split you are limited to splitting codes that don't break the surrounding code such as `<br>` tags. I need to split using a `</div><div>` in that order to close the surrounding tag and reopen it for each page used by another javascript snippet to render each page in a flip book manner.

This is the code I have so far along with sample data:

```html
<?php

function htmlWrapThing($str, $size, $breaking){
 $html = false;
 $i = 0;
 $t = 0;
$tagcount = 0;
 $chars = str_split($str);
 $return = "";
 $break = false;
 $tag = "";
$newtag="";
 foreach($chars as $char){
  if($char=="<"){ 
$tagcount++;
$html = true;
}
  if($char==">") $html = false;
  
if(($tagcount/2)>1){
  $tagcount =  0;
  $tag = "";
  }


  if($html) $t++;
  if($html && $char!="/" && $t > 1){
  $tag .= $char;
  $t =0;
  }

  

  if(!$html) $i++;
  $return .= $char;
  if($i==$size) $break = true;
  if($char == " " && !$html && $break){
   
   
if(!isset($tag)||$tag==""){
  $return .= $breaking;
}else{
$return .= '</'.$tag.'>'.$breaking.'<'.$tag.'>';

}
    
    
   $i=0;
   
   

   $break = false;
  }

   

 }
 return $return;
}

$str = "<h1>hilo everybody how is everyone doing tonight?</h1><p>hello world how is everyone doing today</p><p>hello world how is everyone doing today</p><p>hello world how is everyone doing today</p><br><br />hello everybody how are you doing today?";

echo '<div class="pagecontent">'.htmlWrapThing($str,10, '</div><div class="pagecontent">').'</div>';
```

This generates output like this:

```html
<div class="pagecontent"><h1>hilo everybody </h></div><div class="pagecontent"><h>how is everyone </h></div><div class="pagecontent"><h>doing tonight?</h1><p>hello </<></div><div class="pagecontent"><<>world how </<></div><div class="pagecontent"><<>is everyone </<></div><div class="pagecontent"><<>doing today</p><p>hello </<<pp></div><div class="pagecontent"><<<pp>world how </<<pp></div><div class="pagecontent"><<<pp>is everyone </<<pp></div><div class="pagecontent"><<<pp>doing today</p><p>hello </pp></div><div class="pagecontent"><pp>world how </pp></div><div class="pagecontent"><pp>is everyone </pp></div><div class="pagecontent"><pp>doing today</p><br><br />hello </b<r></div><div class="pagecontent"><b<r>everybody </b<r></div><div class="pagecontent"><b<r>how are you </b<r></div><div class="pagecontent"><b<r>doing today?</div>
```

When I need it to be more like this:

```html
<div class="pagecontent"><h1>hilo everybody </h1></div>
<div class="pagecontent"><h1>1how is everyone </h1></div>
<div class="pagecontent"><h1>doing tonight?</h1><p>hello </p></div>
<div class="pagecontent"><p>world how </p></div>
<div class="pagecontent"><p>is everyone </p></div>
<div class="pagecontent"><p>doing today</p><p>hello </p></div>
<div class="pagecontent"><p>world how </p></div>
  <div class="pagecontent"><p>is everyone </p></div>
    <div class="pagecontent"><p>doing today</p><p>hello </p></div>
    <div class="pagecontent"><p>world how </p></div>
    <div class="pagecontent"><p>is everyone </p></div>
    <div class="pagecontent"><p>doing today</p><br><br />hello</div><div class="pagecontent">everybody </div>
    <div class="pagecontent">how are you</div>
    <div class="pagecontent">doing today?</div>
```

As you can see it is getting the reinserted tags all messed up. any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated so it doesn't break in the middle of a word.

I just threw this together. Seems to work fine with your test string.

Here's a [PHP-fiddle-type-thing](http://3v4l.org/VkJkT)

```
function htmlWrapThing($str, $size){ 
    $html = false; 
    $i = 0; 
    $chars = str_split($str); 
    $return = ""; 
    $break = false; 
    foreach($chars as $char){ 
        if($char=="<") $html = true; 
        if($char==">") $html = false; 
        if(!$html) $i++; $return .= $char; 
        if($i==$size) $break = true; 
        if($char == " " && !$html && $break){ 
            $return .= "<br>"; 
            $i=0; $break = false; 
        } 
    } 
    return $return; 
}
```

Just for fun, here's that same function slightly modified for use in JS. And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vp5ak3pp/1/), too.

```
function HtmlTrimThing($chars, $size){
    $html = false; 
    $break = false;
    $i = 0; 
    $return = ""; 
    $c = $d = $chars.length;
    while($c--){
        $char = $chars[$d-$c-1];
        if($char=="<") $html = true; 
        if($char==">") $html = false; 
        if(!$html) $i++; 
        $return += $char; 
        if($i==$size) $break = true;
        if($break && $char == " " && !$html){ 
            $return += "<br>"; 
            $i=0; 
            $break = false;
        } 
    } 
    return $return; 
}
```

Comment: While this doesn't counter balance h1 tags this works incredible well and you replied so quickly I wish i could give you a million high fives because this works so well!

Comment: @BlaineA.Miller I don't understand what you mean by counterbalance h1 tags. If you could try and explain it al little better maybe I could work that in.

Comment: Basically an h1 tag is at the beginning of each run of this function and the css makes those display bigger and i need to adjust the size of that page and where it breaks in order get it display properly. so for example if the html tag is an h1 modify the size of that current page break by a reduction of say 200 characters and leave the rest of the pages alone for each break after that.

Comment: @BlaineA.Miller So, if I follow, you want any text within a header tag should break after, say, 200 letters whereas the rest of the content should break after, say, 1100?

Comment: sort of but not exactly 200 characters but more of an offset of 200 say like 1100 - 200 for the first section of the text that contains an h1 tag and the rest will remain at 1100 but i think i was able to modify the code you provided to achieve primarily what i was going for. I will post it as an edit to my original post and mark yours as correct.

Comment: I was wrong in my interpretation of your code. While it worked perfectly with the sample data I provided it will not answer my problem i was having all the time as the updated post states. I do appreciate your help very much and I hope you will still be able to assist me with the more clear version of my problem listed above. I excluded the offset portion primarily because I can figure that out based on the code you provided. If you could take a second look I would be most grateful.

Comment: @BlaineA.Miller.. I spent 30 minutes on your problem the other day and you can't even give me an upvote so no, i'm not going to help you anymore. If you have a new question you need to ask a new question, but beware, your participation will effect how willing people are to help you.